# Applying time-variant filter in Python

Tags: python, filtering, signal-processing

I'm attempting to apply a bandpass filter with time-varying cutoff frequencies to a signal, using Python. The routine I am currently using partitions my signal into equal-length time segments, then for each segment I apply a filter with time-specific parameters, before merging the signal back together. The parameters are based on pre-existing estimates.

The problem I seem to be having is that there are "ripples" at the edge of each time-segment that appear after the filter has been applied. This causes discontinuities in my signal, which interfere with my post-filtering data analysis.

I was hoping someone could inform me whether there are any existing routines for implementing filters with time-varying parameters in Python? Alternatively, advice on how I might get around this problem would be much appreciated.

**EDIT** -- example of what I want to do is added below.

Let's say I have a signal x(t). I want to filter the first half with a bandpass filter with parameters (100,200) Hz. The second half I want to filter with parameters (140, 240) Hz. I iterate over x(t), applying my filter to each half, then recombine the results. Some example code might look like:

```
outputArray = np.empty(len(x))
segmentSize = len(x) / 2
filtParams  = [(100, 200), (140, 240)]

for i in range(2):
    tempData     = x[i*segmentSize:(i+1)*segmentSize]
    tempFiltered = bandPassFilter(tempData, parameters=filtParams[i])
    outputArray[i*segmentSize:(i+1)*segmentSize] = tempFiltered
```

(To save space let's assume I have a function which performs bandpass filtering).

As you can see, the data segments do not overlap and are simply "pasted" back together in the new array.

**EDIT 2** -- some sample code of my problem @H.D.

First of all, thanks for your significant input thus far. The audiolazy package looks like a great tool.

I thought it would be a bit more useful if I describe my goals in further detail. As I have posted [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302240/filter-design-and-frequency-extraction-in-python), I am attempting to extract the [instantaneous frequency](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Hilbert-Huang_transform#Instantaneous_frequency_and_the_Hilbert_transform) (IF) of a signal, using the Hilbert transform. My data contains significant noise but I have a good estimate of the bandwidth where my IF signal lies. A problem I have come up against, however, is that 
the IF is often nonstationary. Using a "static" filter approach I am often therefore required to use a broad bandpass region, to ensure all frequencies are captured.

The following code demonstrates the effect of increasing the filter bandwidth on an IF signal. It includes a signal generating function, an implementation of a bandpass filter using the scipy.signal package, and a method to extract the IF of the resultant filtered signal.

```
from audiolazy import *
import scipy.signal as sig
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

def sineGenerator( ts, f, rate, noiseLevel=None ):
    """generate a sine tone with time, frequency, sample rate and noise specified"""

    fs = np.ones(len(ts)) * f    
    y  = np.sin(2*np.pi*fs*ts)

    if noiseLevel: y = y + np.random.randn(len(y))/float(noiseLevel)
    return y

def bandPassFilter( y, passFreqs, rate, order ):
    """STATIC bandpass filter using scipy.signal Butterworth filter"""

    nyquist = rate / 2.0
    Wn      = np.array([passFreqs[0]/nyquist, passFreqs[1]/nyquist])    
    z, p, k = sig.butter(order, Wn, btype='bandpass', output='zpk')
    b, a    = sig.zpk2tf(z, p, k)

    return sig.lfilter(b, a, y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     rate = 1e4
     ts   = np.arange(0, 10, 1/rate)

     # CHANGING THE FILTER AFFECTS THE LEVEL OF NOISE
     ys    = sineGenerator(ts, 600.0, 1e4, noiseLevel=1.0) # a 600Hz signal with noise
     filts = [[500, 700], [550, 650], [580, 620]]

    for f in filts:
        tempFilt = bandPassFilter( ys, f, rate, order=2 )
        tempFreq = instantaneousFrequency( tempFilt, rate )

        plot( ts[1:], tempFreq, alpha=.7, label=str(f).strip('[]') )

    ylim( 500, 750 )
    xlabel( 'time' )
    ylabel( 'instantaneous frequency (Hz)' )

    legend(frameon=False)
    title('changing filter passband and instantaneous frequency')
    savefig('changingPassBand.png')
```

[image: changing passband]

There is a single frequency component in the signal (at 600Hz). The legend shows the filter parameters used in each case. Using a narrower "static" filter gives a "cleaner" output. But how narrow my filter can be is limited by what the frequencies are. For instance, consider the following signal with two frequency components (one at 600Hz, another at 650Hz).

[image: varying frequency]

In this example I have been forced to use a broader bandpass filter, which has resulted in extra noise creeping in to the IF data.

**My idea is that by using a time varying filter, I can "optimise" the filter for my signal at certain time increments.** So for the above signal I might want to filter around 580-620Hz for the first 5 seconds, then 630-670Hz for the next 5 seconds. Essentially I want to minimise noise in the final IF signal.

Based on the example code you sent I have written a function that uses audiolazy to implement a static Butterworth filter on a signal.

```
def audioLazyFilter( y, rate, Wp, Ws ):
    """implement a Butterworth filter using audiolazy"""

    s, Hz = sHz(rate)
    Wp    = Wp * Hz # Bandpass range in rad/sample
    Ws    = Ws * Hz # Bandstop range in rad/sample

    order, new_wp_divpi = sig.buttord(Wp/np.pi, Ws/np.pi, gpass=dB10(.6), gstop=dB10(.1))
    ssfilt = sig.butter(order, new_wp_divpi, btype='bandpass')
    filt_butter = ZFilter(ssfilt[0].tolist(), ssfilt[1].tolist())

    return list(filt_butter(y))
```

The IF data obtained using this filter in conjunction with the Hilbert transform routine compares well to those obtained using scipy.signal:

```
AL_filtered = audioLazyFilter( ys, rate, np.array([580, 620]), np.array([570, 630]) )
SP_filtered = bandPassFilter( ys, [580, 620], rate, order=2 )
plot(ts[1:], instantaneousFrequency( SP_filtered, 1e4 ), alpha=.75, label='scipy.signal Butterworth filter')
plot(ts[1:], instantaneousFrequency( AL_filtered, 1e4 ), 'r', alpha=.75, label='audiolazy Butterworth filter')
```

[image: compare audiolazy with scipy.signal]

My question is now can I combine the audiolazy Butterworth routine with the time-varying properties you described in your original posts?

Comment: Can you add an example of what you're trying to achieve? It is not exactly clear to me what you mean with "time varying": your filter will, at best, have a response time (tapped delay), so changing your filter parameters in time will create all kinds of effects in your output signal. It is not clear to me how you intend to concatenate your signals in the post processing.

Comment: @Ludo Please see my edit above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[AudioLazy](https://github.com/danilobellini/audiolazy) works natively with time varying filters

```
from audiolazy import sHz, white_noise, line, resonator, AudioIO

rate = 44100
s, Hz = sHz(rate)

sig = white_noise() # Endless white noise Stream

dur = 8 * s # Some few seconds of audio
freq = line(dur, 200, 800) # A lazy iterable range
bw = line(dur, 100, 240)

filt = resonator(freq * Hz, bw * Hz) # A simple bandpass filter

with AudioIO(True) as player:
  player.play(filt(sig), rate=rate)
```

You can also use it for plotting (or analysis, in general), by using `list(filt(sig))` or `filt(sig).take(inf)`. There are a lot of other resources that might be useful as well, such as applying time-varying coefficients directly in a Z-transform filter equation.

**EDIT: More information about the AudioLazy components**

The following examples were done using the IPython.

Resonator is a `StrategyDict` instance, which ties many implementations in one place.

```
In [1]: from audiolazy import *

In [2]: resonator
Out[2]: 
{('freq_poles_exp',): <function audiolazy.lazy_filters.freq_poles_exp>,
 ('freq_z_exp',): <function audiolazy.lazy_filters.freq_z_exp>,
 ('poles_exp',): <function audiolazy.lazy_filters.poles_exp>,
 ('z_exp',): <function audiolazy.lazy_filters.z_exp>}

In [3]: resonator.default
Out[3]: <function audiolazy.lazy_filters.poles_exp>
```

So `resonator` calls internally the `resonator.poles_exp` function, from which you can get some help

```
In [4]: resonator.poles_exp?
Type:       function
String Form:<function poles_exp at 0x2a55b18>
File:       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/audiolazy/lazy_filters.py
Definition: resonator.poles_exp(freq, bandwidth)
Docstring:
Resonator filter with 2-poles (conjugated pair) and no zeros (constant
numerator), with exponential approximation for bandwidth calculation.

Parameters
----------
freq :
  Resonant frequency in rad/sample (max gain).
bandwidth :
  Bandwidth frequency range in rad/sample following the equation:

    ``R = exp(-bandwidth / 2)``

  where R is the pole amplitude (radius).

Returns
-------
A ZFilter object.
Gain is normalized to have peak with 0 dB (1.0 amplitude).
```

So a verbose filter assignment would be

```
filt = resonator.poles_exp(freq=freq * Hz, bandwidth=bw * Hz)
```

Where the `Hz` is just a number to change the unit from Hz to rad/sample, as used in most AudioLazy components.

Let's do so with `freq = pi/4` and `bw = pi/8` (`pi` is already in the `audiolazy` namespace):

```
In [5]: filt = resonator(freq=pi/4, bandwidth=pi/8)

In [6]: filt
Out[6]: 
              0.233921
------------------------------------
1 - 1.14005 * z^-1 + 0.675232 * z^-2


In [7]: type(filt)
Out[7]: audiolazy.lazy_filters.ZFilter
```

You can try using this filter instead of the one given in the first example.

Another way to do so would be using the `z` object from the package.
First let's find the constants for that all-poles resonator:

```
In [8]: freq, bw = pi/4, pi/8

In [9]: R = e ** (-bw / 2)

In [10]: c = cos(freq) * 2 * R / (1 + R ** 2) # AudioLazy included the cosine

In [11]: gain = (1 - R ** 2) * sqrt(1 - c ** 2)
```

The denominator can be done directly by using the `z` in the equation:

```
In [12]: denominator = 1 - 2 * R * c * z ** -1 + R ** 2 * z ** -2

In [13]: gain / denominator
Out[14]: 
              0.233921
------------------------------------
1 - 1.14005 * z^-1 + 0.675232 * z^-2

In [15]: type(_) # The "_" is the last returned value in IPython
Out[15]: audiolazy.lazy_filters.ZFilter
```

**EDIT 2: About the time varying coefficients**

The filter coefficients can also be a Stream instance (which can be cast from any iterable).

```
In [16]: coeff = Stream([1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1]) # Cast from a list

In [17]: (1 - coeff * z ** -2)(impulse()).take(inf)
Out[17]: [1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

The same, given a list input instead of the `impulse()` Stream:

```
In [18]: coeff = Stream((1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1)) # Cast from a tuple 

In [19]: (1 - coeff * z ** -2)([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]).take(inf)
Out[19]: [1.0, 0.0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

A NumPy 1D array is also an iterable:

```
In [20]: from numpy import array

In [21]: array_data = array([1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1])

In [22]: coeff = Stream(array_data) # Cast from an array

In [23]: (1 - coeff * z ** -2)([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]).take(inf)
Out[23]: [0.0, 1.0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

This last example shows the time-variant behaviour.

**EDIT 3: Chunked-repeat sequences behaviour**

The line function has a behaviour similar to the `numpy.linspace`, which gets the range "length" instead of "step".

```
In [24]: import numpy

In [25]: numpy.linspace(10, 20, 5) # Start, stop (included), length
Out[25]: array([ 10. ,  12.5,  15. ,  17.5,  20. ])

In [26]: numpy.linspace(10, 20, 5, endpoint=False) # Makes stop not included
Out[26]: array([ 10.,  12.,  14.,  16.,  18.])

In [27]: line(5, 10, 20).take(inf) # Length, start, stop (range-like)
Out[27]: [10.0, 12.0, 14.0, 16.0, 18.0]

In [28]: line(5, 10, 20, finish=True).take(inf) # Include the "stop"
Out[28]: [10.0, 12.5, 15.0, 17.5, 20.0]
```

With that, the filter equation has a different behaviour sample-per-sample (1-sample "chunk"). Anyhow, you can use a repeater for larger chunk sizes:

```
In [29]: five_items = _ # List from the last Out[] value

In [30]: @tostream
   ....: def repeater(sig, n):
   ....:     for el in sig:
   ....:         for _ in xrange(n):
   ....:             yield el
   ....:             

In [31]: repeater(five_items, 2).take(inf)
Out[31]: [10.0, 10.0, 12.5, 12.5, 15.0, 15.0, 17.5, 17.5, 20.0, 20.0]
```

And use it in the line from the first example, so that `freq` and `bw` becomes:

```
chunk_size = 100
freq = repeater(line(dur / chunk_size, 200, 800), chunk_size)
bw = repeater(line(dur / chunk_size, 100, 240), chunk_size)
```

**EDIT 4: Emulating time-varying filters/coefficients from LTI filters using time-varying gain/envelope**

Another way around would be using different "weights" for two different filtered versions of the signal, and making some "crossfade" math with the signal, something like:

```
signal = thub(sig, 2) # T-Hub is a T (tee) auto-copy
filt1(signal) * line(dur, 0, 1) + filt2(signal) * line(dur, 1, 0)
```

This would apply a linear envelope (from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 0) from different filtered versions of the same signal. If `thub` looks confusing, try `sig1, sig2 = tee(sig, 2)` applying `filt(sig1)` and `filt(sig2)` instead, these should do the same.

**EDIT 5: Time-variant Butterworth filter**

I spent the last hours trying to let that Butterworth be personalized as your example, imposing `order = 2` and giving the half-power bandwidth (~3dB) directly. I've done four examples, the code is [in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/danilobellini/6419374), and I've updated AudioLazy to include a `gauss_noise` Gaussian-distributed noise stream. Please note that the code in gist has nothing optimized, it was done ony to work in this particular case, and the chirp example makes it really slow due to a "per sample" coefficient finding behaviour. The instant frequency can be get from the [filtered] data in rad/sample with:

```
diff(unwrap(phase(hilbert(filtered_data))))
```

where `diff = 1 - z ** -1` or another approach to find derivatives in discrete time, `hilbert` is the function from `scipy.signal` that gives us the analytical signal (the Discrete Hilbert Transform is the imaginary part of its result) and the other two are helper functions from AudioLazy.

This is what happens when Butterworth changes its coefficients abruptly while keeping its memory, without noise:

[image: variable_butterworth_abrupt_pure_sinusoid.png]

It's noticeable a oscilatory behaviour in this transition. You can use a moving median to "smooth" that in the lower frequency side while keeping the abrupt transition, but that won't work with the higher frequency. Well, that was what we would expect from a perfect sinusoid, but with noise (a LOT of noise, the Gaussian has the standard deviation equals to the sinusoid amplitude), it becomes:

[image: variable_butterworth_abrupt_noisy.png]

I tried then to do the same with a chirp, precisely this:

[image: variable_butterworth_pure_sinusoid.png]

This shows a strange behaviour when filtering with the lower bandwidth, at the top frequency. And with the additive noise:

[image: variable_butterworth_noisy.png]

The code in gist also `AudioIO().play` this last noisy chirp.

**EDIT 6: Time-variant resonator filter**

I've added to [the same Gist](https://gist.github.com/danilobellini/6419374) an example using resonators instead of Butterworth. They're in pure Python and aren't optimized, but performs faster than calling `butter` for each sample during a chirp, and is far easier to implement, as all the `resonator` strategies accepts Stream instances as valid inputs. Here are the plots for a cascade of two resonators (i.e., a 2nd order filter):

[image: reson_2_abrupt_pure_sinusoid.png]
[image: reson_2_abrupt_noisy.png]
[image: reson_2_pure_sinusoid.png]
[image: reson_2_noisy.png]

And the same for a cascade of three resonators (i.e., a 3nd order filter):

[image: reson_3_abrupt_pure_sinusoid.png]
[image: reson_3_abrupt_noisy.png]
[image: reson_3_pure_sinusoid.png]
[image: reson_3_noisy.png]

These resonators have gain equals to 1 (0 dB) at the center frequency, and that oscillation pattern from the "Abrupt pure sinusoid" plots in the transition happens even without any filtering at all.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I hadn't come across audiolazy before but this could be very useful. In your example above I am assuming that `freq` gives the central point of the bandpass filter, while `bw` gives the bandwidth - is that correct? Is there any more documentation of the type of filter being used? I have previously been using a Butterworth filter. I have another question regarding `freq`: say my Stream is 1000 points long, but I only want to supply filter coefficients for every 100 point "chunks". Is it possible to specify a `line` with these properties?

Comment: Instead of line with the proposed repeater, you can also create your own repeater, or perhaps something like `Stream(100).limit(200).append(240).limit(300)` or `Stream([100] * 200 + [240] * 100)`. Any Stream instance can be used as a coefficient in a Z-Filter in AudioLazy, and Stream intances works with elementwise/broadcast operators like a 1D NumPy Array.

Comment: I'm still struggling to get a simple filter set up. To filter my data thus far I have been using static Butterworth bandpass filters. When I try to develop an analogous filter using audiolazy, there remains significant noise in my data. For instance, say I want to filter a signal using a static bandpass filter with cutoffs at 600 and 700 Hz. This can easily be done with routines in `scipy.signal`. Trying the same in audiolazy I have used `freq=line(dur, 650, 650)`, `bw=line(dur, 50, 50)` and then `filt=resonator(freq*Hz, bw*Hz)`. Could you advise on why the results of both are so different?

Comment: P.S - I can provide some sample data if this would help matters.

Comment: You can still use the same Butterworth filters from scipy, they probably are of higher order than the resonator I've suggest, can you show how you're using them?

Comment: AudioLazy plots with SciPy Butterworth filters: https://github.com/danilobellini/audiolazy/blob/master/audiolazy/examples/butterworth_scipy.py ; You can try also with `resonator.z_exp` instead of the default `resonator.poles_exp`.

Comment: Please see the update to my original post for further comments. If anything is unclear please let me know.

Comment: Once again thanks for the time you have put into this. I'm currently trialling the moving Butterworth filter, but given the stated slowness in the routine I wanted to pose yet _another_ question. Essentially the reason I've chosen to use a Butterworth filter is due to its flat response in the passband and rapid attenuation at the cutoff frequencies (when used with a suitable order). However I'd be amenable to using a different, but equivalent response, filter if necessary, to speed up the time-variant factor. Can such a filter be designed in audiolazy?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understood or not what you meant with "speed up the time-variant factor". The slowness happens mostly in the chirp version, because there's one designed filter per sample (i.e., one call to scipy.signal.butter per sample during the chirp), from which the coefficients are found. The abrupt transition is faster since there's only 2 filters being designed: one for the higher and one for the lower frequency. To be faster you can interpolate the coefficients instead of re-designing the filter in each sample, but that would be another approach.

Comment: I've updated the answer, adding cascaded resonators as a simple alternative to the Butterworth filters.

Comment: With regards to the speed in the time-variant factor, I think your answer addresses it. Essentially I was asking if there was another filter I could use that would speed up the process, but that gave a similar response to Butterworth. Your updated response is great, and I'll look into it more. With regards to my data, redesigning the filter at each sample is not practical (there are millions of samples per signal). However what I do have is an estimate of the freq coefficients aggregated over every few hundred thousand points, i.e. frequency is varies more slowly at shorter time scales.

Comment: I'm having some success with your implementation, which is great. The CascadeFilter is a little slow, but does the job. I was just wondering, however, if there is a forward-backward filter implementation of the audiolazy filters, analagous to `scipy.signal.filtfilt`?

Answer (score 1):

Try filtering the whole signal with each filter you're using, then merge the filtered signals appropriately. Roughly, in pseudocode:

```
# each filter acts on the entire signal with each cutoff frequency
s1 = filter1(signal)
s2 = filter2(signal)
s3 = filter3(signal)

filtered_signal = s1[0:t1] + s2[t1:t2] + s3[t2:t3]
```

I think this will avoid the artifacts you're describing that result from chopping up the signal then filtering.

Another possibility is using a [Short Time Fourier Transform (STFT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform#Inverse_STFT).  Here's [an implementation using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6891772/1460057).

Basically, you could STFT your signal, filter your signal by operating on the time-frequency array, then inverse STFT the array to get a filtered signal.

You might get even better results using an invertible [wavelet transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_wavelet_transform).  Here's a [paywalled paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8200671) describing how to do pretty much what you're trying to do with a wavelet transform.

Comment: I had considered your first suggestion so will look into it, although I wasn't sure what the running-time trade-off would be (I'm working with fairly large data sets so speed is an important factor). I will post an update when I've had a chance to run some tests. As an aside, I'm trying to extract time-frequency info, which in my signals is nonstationary. Thus any filters designed to be applied to whole signal (rather than smaller chunks, for which the time-frequency data are more approximately stationary) are not really up to scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If you're extracting portions of your signal using slices, then you're effectively windowing your data with a rectangular window, which "rings" at the edges due to the sudden discontinuities. One way to fix this is by using a window that rings less, like a hanning window :

```
import numpy as np

signal = np.random.randn(222)
length = 50
window = np.hanning(length)
for i in range(0, len(signal)-length, length):
    do_filtering(signal[i:i+length] * window)
```

More about windows : http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function

Comment: The rectangular windowing is also something I had considered.. Related to my response to Brionius above, I think the issue with your suggestion may be timing. I have some other functions that use convolution to window my data, which is _much_ quicker than looping, given the size of my input array. Although it's not immediately clear to me how I could combine convolution with a bandpass filter function...